# How to change tr bgcolor inside table in css

Tags: html, css

How to change tr background color which is inside the table with tablename as mytable.
I need to change it using CSS..Is it possible?

Tried this:

```
table {
    width:100%;
}
tr {
    height:50px;
    background:#000000;
}
tr + tr {
    background:#E5F1CC;
}
tr + tr + tr {
    background:#D30A0A;
}
tr + tr + tr + tr {
    background:#656766;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something, please share that

Answer (score 0):

You are going good. You just need to use `:first-child` pseudo-class.

To be specific, try this CSS:

```
table[name="mytable"] {
    width:100%;
}
table[name="mytable"] tr td{
    height:50px;
}
table[name="mytable"] tr:first-child td{
    background:#000000;
}
table[name="mytable"] tr:first-child + tr td{
    background:#E5F1CC;
}
table[name="mytable"] tr:first-child + tr + tr td{
    background:#D30A0A;
}
table[name="mytable"] tr:first-child + tr + tr + tr td{
    background:#656766;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24Fjv/5/)**

Comment: I need to use tablename..how can I use it to change tr bgcolor?

Comment: In order to point out the tr, i m using tablename...how to do that?

Comment: tablename is referred using # and not . (which is for class)

Comment: @DurgeshChaudhary yeah I missed that point.. strange I hope OP means class name though.. even though updated the post.

Comment: You need quotes in there. `[name="mytable"]`

Comment: @David works even without quotes.. but we should be always in safe place. Updated :)

Comment: Regarding your comment to David's (now-deleted) answer; setting the `background-color` Of a `tr` element only works because the descendant `td` elements default to a transparent background colour (though this seems the default in every browser).

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find an example that works: http://jsfiddle.net/DA8z4/

```
table[name="mytable"] tr:first-child td{
    background:red;
}
table[name="mytable"] tr:first-child + tr td{
    background:yellow;
}
table[name="mytable"] tr:first-child + tr + tr td{
    background:blue;
}
```